# Save method in TypeORM not inserting related entity with ID set as null and primaryGeneratedColumn

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm, typegraphql

I’m a bit of a TypeORM newbie, picking up a project and making some changes.
I’m trying to run `asset.save()` with the data at the bottom on a `@OneToMany()` relationship. I’m getting the following error. I’m using type-graphql as well hence the `@Field` decorators.

`QueryFailedError: null value in column "id" of relation "contentBlocks" violates not-null constraint`

I’m passing null for the ID and was expecting it to insert a row given there isn’t one. Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Here is the (abridged) asset class:

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity('assets')
class Asset extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Field(() => User)
  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.assets, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'userId' })
  author: User;

  @Field(() => [ContentBlock], { nullable: true })
  @OneToMany(() => ContentBlock, (contentBlocks) => contentBlocks.asset, { cascade: true, eager: true })
  contentBlocks: ContentBlock[];

}
```

And the corresponding relationship in the contentBlock class with a PrimaryGeneratedColumn set with UUID and allowing null (not sure this is needed):

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity('contentBlocks')
class ContentBlock extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID, { nullable: true })
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string | undefined | null;

  @Field(() => User)
  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.contentBlocks)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'author' })
  author: User;

  @Field(() => Asset)
  @ManyToOne(() => Asset, (asset) => asset.contentBlocks)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'assetId' })
  asset: Asset;
Abridged data being saved.
Asset {
  id: '22958834-15b6-4a83-a1f4-46188b472cc7',
  userId: 'c89a3a6f-c332-4234-8f6c-2232cfa7b49b',
  contentBlocks: [
    {
      id: null,
      body: '<p>Test</p>',
      updatedAt: '2022-09-27T08:20:35.616Z',
      author: [User],
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to save and was expecting TypeORM to insert new rows in the contentBlocks table where the ID is null (i.e. auto-generate the ID). I've also tried deleting the id from the contentBlock as follows: `delete contentBlock.id` inside a map function. This gives the same error.

Comment: Where you able to resolve this?